# T-SQL : Modify table based on dynamic column list

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using ASP.Net with SQL Server 2008. I have a scenario where user can update particular OR all columns. Hence, my optimum solution would be to create a stored procedure in such a way so that I can pass the column names and their corresponding values, and update the table.

One way I know is to create the whole SQL on front end, dynamically, as string and pass it to the stored procedure. Else create the dynamic string inside the stored procedure. But, is that the best option, or can there be a more optimised way?

(I would like to do this in one database trip)

Will appreciate any response that can point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Would it suffice to update columns with their current values? For example: `update Foo set Bar = Coalesce( @Bar, Bar ) where ...`. If the new value in `@Bar` is NULL then the value in the row will be unchanged. If you need to be able to set NULL values then you'll need to be explicit, i.e. `Bar = case when @UpdateBar = 1 then @Bar else Bar end`.

Comment: Yep, it would suffice..I guess that would do the trick. So basically what you are suggesting is that I will be passing the parameters that I need to update , rest remains intact..If yes, then can you please provide a working sample (I think it was in here somewhere..I will try to search again.) Thanks for the response.

Comment: Guys thanks for the responses...I guess I will simply test the passed value for null in the parameter, and if so, update it with it-self else parameter..I guess its the most simple and appropriate way in my scenario... Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can build your T-SQL statement up dynamically within a stored procedure just as you would in `ASP.NET` and then execute the dynamically constructed SQL string with [`@sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

If going this route you'd want to submit your list of column names and values to your stored procedure and then within the stored procedure build up the SQL statement to execute with `@sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to set values to NULL then you can use NULL parameter values to indicate *no change*:

```
 create procedure dbo.UpdateStuff
   @BoxId as Int,
   @Length as Int,
   @Width as Int,
   @Height as Int
 as
   set nocount on
   update Boxes
     set Length = Coalesce( @Length, Length ),
       Width = Coalesce( @Width, Width ), Height = Coalesce( @Height, Height )
     where BoxId = @BoxId
```

If the value NULL is significant then you can use a separate flag to indicate values should be replaced:

```
 create procedure dbo.UpdateStuff
   @BoxId as Int,
   @UpdateLength as Bit,
   @Length as Int,
   @UpdateWidth as Bit,
   @Width as Int,
   @UpdateHeight as Bit,
   @Height as Int
 as
   set nocount on
   update Boxes
     set Length = case when @UpdateLength = 1 then @Length else Length end,
       Width = case when @UpdateWidth = 1 then @Width else Width end,
       Height = case when @UpdateHeight = 1 then @Height else Height end
     where BoxId = @BoxId
```

The two techniques are not mutually exclusive, so you could mix and match styles.